# What does it mean about EXTENDED REVIEW on app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-audience-network

I integrate app on facebook monetization, after few days I see status "APP IN EXTENDED REVIEW". I contact support team and this was reply:

Hi Patrick,

Thank you for reaching out.

I understand that you require clarification on your property which is currently under 'extended review'.

We have recently launched new features which allow us to better assess new apps that onboard onto Audience Network.
You may therefore see your app have the status of “in extended review” when you first onboard it through Monetization Manager.

While we assess your app further during the extended review, your app can start earning up to $25 per day. This will last for around 7 days or until enough traffic has been evaluated.

We seek your kind understanding on this.

Best regards,

I don't why extended review for every app I integrate with facebook monetization. Any idea what am going wrong...

Thanks

Comment: Who said you did anything wrong?

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. Did you find anything helpful?

Comment: It is best, and possibly only, answered by Facebook tech support.

Comment: Does anyone till now received $25 per day (Facebook policy "in extended review")
Please let me know Thanks